# Change of variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have defined several anonymous functions which normally depend on three variables `eta1, eta2, y`. There is the following relationship between `eta1` `eta2` and `y`

```
eta1=@(y) ((i*alpha1*lambda_0)^(1/3))*y+eta01;
eta2=@(y) ((i*alpha2*lambda_0)^(1/3))*y+eta02;
```

So I basically give values for `y` and then I am able to plot `h1b(y=whatever)` via `arrayfun`:

```
DW1=@(eta) blablabla
N3Y=@(y) i*alpha1*(DW1(eta1(y))*conj(U2(eta2(y)))+W1(eta1(y))...
    *conj(DU2(eta2(y))));
h1b=@(y) -(1/(lambda_0*alphats))*(betats*N3Y(y));

vec=arrayfun(h1b,eta1(0:0.01:N));
plot(abs(vec),0:0.01:N)
```

My question: is there a way to retrieve h1b formally depending on `eta1` instead of `y`, as an anonymous function? Without evaluating `y`, subsequently `eta1,eta2` and then `h1b`, which is what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets clarify. So you currently have:

```
syms y eta1 eta2;
eta1(y), eta2(y)
W1(eta1), DW1(eta1)
U2(eta2) DU2(eta2)
```

Hence you also have:

```
N3Y(W1,DW1,U2,DW2)
```

or:

```
N3Y(eta1,eta2)
```

or:

```
N3Y(y)
```

Hence, you have:

```
h1b(N3Y)
```

or:

```
h1b(eta1,eta2)
```

or:

```
 h1b(y)
```

So, `h1b` depends solely on `eta1` and `eta2`, so if you dot want to manipulate kinky `eval` and `simplify` calls, why you just dont create two versions of your functions, one with `y` and other with `eta`s?.

You dont need to rewrite, the `y`s versions are just `eval`uated from the `eta`s versions.